# Как правильно: "во Вкусе Вилл" или во "ВкусВилле"?

Tags: склонение, слитно-раздельно

Все москвичи знают магазин "ВкусВилл". Пишется он вроде в одно слово, но с заглавной буквой второго слова, поэтому можно и воспринимать его как два. Во втором случае возникает падеж: *"во Вкусе Вилл"*. Я так всё время и говорил, но последнее время возникло ощущение, что подавляющее большинство говорит *"во ВкусВилле"*. Они́ правы или всё-таки я?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При формальном употреблении названия, противоречащего русской грамматике (заглавная буква в середине наименования, да ещё в середине слова), его нужно употреблять в именительном падеже (в юридически зафиксированом виде) совместно с видовым наименованием (**в магазине "ВкусВилл"**).

В неофициальных же случаях не видно необходимости ни привязываться к грамматическим особенностям названия (нет грамматически верного способа употребить в предложении что-либо некорректное, кроме его цитирования), ни искать в нём внутренний смысл: я бы на письме "обеззаглавил" грамматически проблемную букву (**во "Вкусвилле"**), сохранив одно слово, - что и наблюдается (не знаю, доходит ли до написания, но вторую заглавную букву выговорить в таком качестве всё равно нельзя). Если же название имеет убедительно разъясняемый смысл вроде "производства продуктов на виллах людьми со вкусом", то можно, проникнувшись к предпринимателям уважением, написать: **во "Вкусе вилл"**.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Всё-таки Вы, как я понял, на стороне большинства, да (во Вкуссвилле)?

Comment: Мне смысл названия кажется настолько странным, что не хочется рассматривать его как словосочетание :).

Comment: Ну понятно. Видимо, и большинство тем же руководствуется, и все вы правы. Надо переучиваться. :)

Answer (score 1):

На [сайте компании](http://vkusvill.ru/about) можно найти объяснение названию ВкусВилл.

> «Причем здесь вилы и их вкус?», – спрашивали у нас люди. Поначалу мы терпеливо объясняли, что «вилл» - это образование от слова village. Если дословно, что-то вроде вкусной деревни. Но через некоторое время поняли, что вариант с вилами тоже вполне концептуален. И стали вместе с покупателями смеяться над шутками в стиле: «Ох, уж этот беспощадный нэйминг».

Все-таки название было задумано как сокращение от "вкусный village" (аналогия: РусЯз), а не как "Вкус Вил". К тому же удвоенное Л не дает всерьез говорить о вилах. Естественное решение (только для неофициальных случаев, конечно): **во “ВкусВилле”** (аналогия: в РусЯзе).

Comment: Так я про "вилы" (с одной Л) вообще и не думал даже!

Comment: Так или иначе, чтобы склонять первое слово, нужно найти смысл не только для него, но и для второго слова тоже. Так как фирма эта не виллами (шикарными домами) занимается, то "Вкус вилл" не подходит по смыслу. Вариант *во "Вкусе Вилл"* ничем не оправдан.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже переучился и говорю "во Вкусвилле". :)

Answer (score 0):

При чем здесь вкус вилл или вил?)))  Вкусвилл - как название городка, как Хантсвилл, Бельвилл, Амитивилл, Джексонвилл и так далее)

Comment: Попробуйте дополнить Ваш постинг, чтобы он превратился в полноценный ответ на заданный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже говорю во Вкусе Вилл, даже после разговора с дочкой, которая с легкостью произносит во Вкусвилле. И легко нахожу своему варианту логичное объяснение: дорого и натурально.

Answer (score -1):

Вкус (чего?) Вилл (вилла). Мне кажется тоже логично склонять первое слово.

Comment: См. комментарии к моему ответу